# difference between touchMoved and Swipe?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

i am rotating circle in iPad.i have inserted swipegesture event.but I want to different operations in touchMoved and swipeEvent.but when I do touch moving , swipw gesture is called, what i have to do , any help please?

Answer (score 2):

swipe:

NSEventTypeSwipe
An event representing a swipe gesture.
Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later.
Declared in NSEvent.h.

and

touchMoved:

Sent to the receiver when one or more fingers move in the associated view.

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

so swipe cant be use to code some thing when any thing happens like touches.swipe is use for recognizing touch event.

Comment: check in help NSEvent.I think no event like that but you can identify in touchMoved.check this link http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2009/07/23/simple-swipe-detection-in-the-iphone-sdk/